# heroku Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory - /assets/)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a problem that occurs **only** in a production environment, deployed at heroku.

The Heroku logs says:

```
[...]
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
             "authenticity_token"=>"...", 
             "users"=>{"name"=>"name", "email"=>"example@example.com", 
             "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
             "commit"=>"Join Us!"}

Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
Rendered notifier/new_user_creation.html.erb (0.7ms)
heroku[router]: POST stark-blabla-345.herokuapp.com/users dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms
service=333ms status=500 bytes=643
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 284ms
app[web.1]: Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory - /assets/):***   
app[web.1]: app/controllers/users_controller.rb:13:in `create
```

This error happened after adding a Mailer component with these characteristics:

```
class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "..."

  def new_user_creation(user)
    @user = user
    @url= "http://stark-blabla-345.herokuapp.com/users/
                  #{user.create_digitally_signed_remember_token}/confirm"
    mail to:user.email, subject: 'bla bla, complete the registration process'   

  end

end
```

with the following templete new_user_creation.html.erb :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <title><%=t("confirm_account_creation")%></title>
      <style type="text/css">
          body{ background:#f1f1ee; }
         .title{font-size: 300%; font-family: Georgia, serif; font-weight:bold;}  
         .indented{margin-left:5%; padding:1%;}
      </style>
  </head>

<body>
  <table width="100%" id="background" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="http://stark-blabla-345.herokuapp.com/assets/
          red_flower-a4105a7cc626711e8789b1c2b21777b6.png"
          align="middle">
        <span class="title"><%=t("base_title")%></span>
      </td>
   </tr>  

   <tr>
     <td>
       <p class="indented"><%=t("confirm_account_creation")%><p>
       <p class="indented"><a href="<%=@url%>">COMPLETE ACCOUNT CREATION PROCESS</a></p>
     </td>
   </tr>


  </table>  

</body>

</html>
```

UsersController#create():

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:users])
  if @user.save 
    Notifier.new_user_creation(@user).deliver
    flash.now[:block] = t("users.create.created")
    render "confirm_registration"    
  else
    render 'new'
  end     
end
```

My Gemfile :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'
gem 'rails', '3.2.6'
gem "heroku"
# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "paperclip", "2.7.0" # :git => "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'premailer-rails3'  

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :test,:development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'rspec-rails','2.9.0'
  gem 'execjs'
  gem 'annotate', '~> 2.4.1.beta'
end

group :test do
  gem 'spork' 
  gem 'cucumber-rails', require:false;
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'factory_girl'
  gem "launchy"
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'thin'
end
```

The interesting part of production.rb:

```
MyApp::Application.configure do
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = 
     { host: "stark-blabla-345.herokuapp.com" }
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false # the same with true 
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    domain: "stark-blabla-345.herokuapp.com",
    authentication: "plain",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
    password:  ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]
  }

end
```

Comment: In $RAILS/assets are the usual contents: images,stylesheets and javascripts. Perhaps is also interesting production.rb :

Comment: It's happening for me in development and test as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the `premailer-rails3` gem? I found that version 1.2.0 caused this exact same problem. Downgrading to 1.1.0 fixed it. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you KendallB!! Yes, in fact I was just using premailer 1.7.3. Downgrading to 1.1.0 worked for me too.

Comment: @StenKaRazin, you should accept and upvote this answer if it worked for you. (I'm having the same problem so it would be useful to confirm that this is the complete solution.) :)

Comment: This has been fixed in the `master` branch: https://github.com/fphilipe/premailer-rails3/issues/41

Answer (score 3):

This is not a heroku-only issue. This exception is thrown when `email.css` does not exist or (as of premailer-rails 1.3.x) a inline `style` tag [does not exist](https://github.com/fphilipe/premailer-rails3/commit/4410d4ab4b3fe83de27d05b52e916b98afb94f15).

The solution is to add `email.css` to your assets folder or add an empty `<style type="text/css"> </style>` to your email HTML.

Answer (score 3):

Been struggling with this for a number of hours and thought I would add my solution for your benefit.

Using premailer-rails3 (1.3.1)

I wanted my email CSS to match the bootstrap styling, so I thought a lazy way would be to simply use `<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>` however this causes the cannot find /assets/ issue.

So I ended up doing the following:

1. Needed to remove `*= require_tree` from  my `application.css`, which is good practice anyway, and required by main css file

> ```
> *= require_self
> *= require <MyMainSiteCSS>
> */
> ```

1. Created `app/stylesheets/email.css` with the following

> ```
> @import "bootstrap";
> @import "bootstrap-responsive";
> ```

1. Changed the head of my email view to be:

> ```
> <head>
>   <link href="email.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
> </head>
> ```

So, now everything is working and I have great bootstrap styling in my emails.